# How to get Facebook photo privacy settings via GRAPH API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

There is no mention of privacy for Photo object,-
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

But its possible to get/set the same for each photo via FB website. So is it possible using GRAPH/FQL to get/set privacy settings for Photo?

Answer (score 1):

For getting the value: see Lix's response.

For setting the value:

Without the column exposed via the API, it's not going to be possible to change/update its privacy.  I can see this being a great bug for you to log at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion, reported the same there :)

Comment: Can you post your bug # here so people who stumble across this StackOverflow Question can see it?

Comment: Sorry all for late reply, u can find my reported bug in that site, the title is "No GRAPH API to get/set privacy setting of Photo object"
url:- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/362056393820446?browse=search_4f1c2eb0f1f8f1386306789

Facebook has said that they will add this feature to wishlist :)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from two special albums, namely "mobile uploads" and "wall photos", photo privacy is governed by the album (same on Facebook web too so the bug request won't help here). If you post to me/photos then you are posting to an album auto created for your app. You can post to any album by posting to albumid/photos.

The good news is that you can set the album privacy for an album that you create via the Graph API. See the "albums" section [on this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).